# How to fix "Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined" error in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using this.props.navigator.push method in react native. That was working fine but now i am getting error "Cannot read property 'navigator' of undefined"

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    screen: "awesome-Projects.DashBoardScreen",
    title: "Dash Board"
});
```

Expected Result: Go to Dash Board
Actual result: remain on same page

Comment: which navigation are you using ?

Comment: Please provide some more detail. Add some other code also.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your this.props is undefined.Mostly it is caused by that `this` is directed to another scope.